# ¿ Como manipular svg con css?

Tags: html, css, xml, aplicación-web, svg

estoy tratando de manipular imágenes svg con css y realmente no he tenido el mas mínimo éxito, supongo que es algún detalle que no estoy haciendo ya que en internet hay muchos ejemplos de esto que estoy intentando e imagino que es porque les funciona a todos, pero yo no he podido ni colocando el svg en el html directamente, ni a través de una etiqueta img, ni con el css en el html o en el svg tanto internamente como externamente, de verdad no he podido, si alguien sabe hacerlo se lo agradezco. A continuación les dejo mi código:

vector.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vector</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  *
  {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
  }

  html, body
  {
   height: 100%;
  }

  body
  {
   background-color: red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="img/drawing.svg" alt="svg">
</body>
</html>
```

drawing.svg - El archivo fue creado con inkscape, solo quiero cambiar el color del cuadro, por ahora, pero ni eso he podido hacer. El atributo `class="cuadrado"` lo coloque yo manualmente, y como se podrán fijar en la segunda linea del codigo, estoy insertando el css en la imagen svg de manera externa.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="epa.css"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   height="297mm"
   width="210mm">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       y="233.69289"
       x="102.70579"
       height="270.90512"
       width="315.55981"
       id="rect3336"
       style="fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1"
       class="cuadrado"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

epa.css - Este archivo esta en la misma carpeta de la imagen svg, y como podrán ver es muy muy básico.

```css
#rect3336
{
  fill: blue;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
```

El archivo "svg" y el archivo "css" están en una carpeta llamada "img", el archivo "vector.html" esta en la carpeta principal, es decir "img" es una subcarpeta. Espero me ayuden.

Comment: Debes declararlo en línea, lo suyo es crear un mapa de svgs y utilizar algún task runner para compilar las imágenes. En https://www.paradigmadigital.com/dev/color-iconos-svg/ podrás ver ejemplos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás muy cerca, para no modificar tu SVG agrégale el infortunado `!important` para que sobreescriba el estilo inline:

```css
#rect3336 {
   fill:#ff0000 !important;
  }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="epa.css"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   height="297mm"
   width="210mm">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       y="233.69289"
       x="102.70579"
       height="270.90512"
       width="315.55981"
       id="rect3336"
       style="fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1"
       class="cuadrado"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Dependiendo como desees manejar tus SVG podrías hacerlo de otra forma:

- No aplicarle ningún estilo (inline) al SVG como tal y hacerlo completamente desde tu hoja de estilos.
- Crear un SVG sprite para poder agruparlos y referenciarlos todos en el mismo archivo.

---

Edición para usar hojas de estilo externas:

Normalmente para usar hojas de estilo externas, suelo agrupar los svg en un solo archivo y referenciarlos allí:

**imagenes.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="cuadrado" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047" height="297mm" width="210mm">
      <rect
        y="233.69289"
        x="102.70579"
        height="270.90512"
        width="315.55981"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- otros svg -->
  </svg>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vector</title>
    <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <svg class="imagen1">
      <use xlink:href="imagenes.svg#cuadrado"></use>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

**estilo.css**

```
.imagen1 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Comment: Hola Shaz, coloque el código con "!important" justo antes de la etiqueta "defs" , dentro de etiquetas "style" y me funciona de esa manera, pero no me funciona con un archivo externo como lo estoy intentando hacer, es decir con "epa.css", alguna idea ?

Comment: Edité la respuesta para mostrar como utilizar SVG con estilos externos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría sería convertir el SVG en una fuente que son mucho más fáciles de modificar con css.

échale un vistazo a esta extensión de chrome

https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Answer (score 1):

Cre que es por usar el svg externo, al ser externo sus partes no hacen parte del DOM y por eso el css no puede leerlossi cortas y pegas el svg en el html funciona, tambien estoy mirando como resolver eso usando un svg externo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar los atributos dentro del archivo SVG, sin necesidad de tener un CSS.
Para esto tiene que insertar la imagen dentro de la pagina cargandolo desde un directorio que tengas en la aplicacion. El codigo para poner la imagen seria:

```
<object id="diagrama" type="image/svg+xml" data="Imagen/Cavas Pedriel C.svg" style="border: medium ridge #C0C0C0; width: auto; height: 480px;"></object>
```

Luego creas una funcion en donde buscas el elemento dentro del SVG a cambiar el color.

> Para saber como se llama el elemento podes utilizar Inkscape, cargas
>   la imagen SVG, selecciona la imagen, y desagrupa todos los elementos (boton derecho sobre la imagen -> Ungroup.
>
> Marcas cual es el que queres cambiar la propiedad y presiona
>   ctrl+shift+O, en la pantalla se habre una nueva ventana adonde estan
>   las propiedades del elemento, esta el nombre Id:**patch458** 
>   por ejemplo.
>
> Podes cambiarle el nombre si queres editando 
>   este campo y luego presionar Apply que esta abajo en la
>   ventana. No olvides grabar los cambio en la imagen.
>
> Este es el nombre de lo que queres cambiar, recordalo para poder buscarloen la aplicacion.

El la pagina creas un funcion que llamas para cambiar el color, la cual tendria:

```
 {
 var a = document.getElementById("diagrama");  // "diagrama" es el nombre del contenedor de la imagen en la pagina
       var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //cargo el contenido de la imagen SVG
       temp = "patch458" ;  //nombre del elemento a cambiar
       var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById(temp); //busco dentro de la imagen el Id que corresponde cargado en temp.
       svgItem.style.setProperty("fill", "red", "");// defino la propiedad fill del elemento seleccionado de color rojo
     }
```

Espero que les sirva.

Saludos